# Android translucent theme not working

Tags: android, transparency, android-launcher

I've been stuck all day long with this problem.
I want to create my own launcher and I want it to have transparent both status and navigation bars like google now launcher on 4.4+.
Tuts on internet show all the same code to add to my app but it seems like there's something wrong with mine.

What I got from using `android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor`
as well as

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

is this:
http://i.imgur.com/RaRQvPc.png
Instead of the the normal behave like other launchers. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Actually this work on my emulator with KitKat, target version is 19.
It seems like having trouble on api 20 only, so how did google and others managed to keep the translucent view even in Android L preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this got an answer here:
[Android 4.4 translucent Status and Navigation bars style on Android 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474125/android-4-4-translucent-status-and-navigation-bars-style-on-android-5-0)

For both status and navigation:

In your style:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

And in Java:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```