# Android 4.4 translucent Status and Navigation bars style on Android 5.0

Tags: android, statusbar, navigationbar, android-5.0-lollipop

On Android 4.4 KitKat you can set the Status and Navigation bars transparent with the `android:windowTranslucentStatus` and `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` theme elements, and then below the bars the app window is extended and a gradient is added. However on Android 5.0 Lollipop this has been changed and now instead of the gradient a solid transparent color is added. Android 5.0 offers the new `android:statusBarColor` and `android:navigationBarColor` elements under the new Material theme, but when you try to set these elements to `@android:color/transparent` the app window is not extended, and if you use `android:windowTranslucentStatus` and `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` then `android:statusBarColor` and `android:navigationBarColor` are ignored.

Am I missing something described on http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar?

[image]

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Set `android:windowTranslucentStatus` to *false* and set `android:statusBarColor` to `@android:color/transparent`.

Then add code below:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

If you also want the navigation bar to be translucent, set `android:navigationBarColor` to `@android:color/transparent` and combine the flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION` as well.

I didn't experiment on the navigation bar but it will work.

Comment: Great! This works for both the System and the Navigation bar. I don't understand why this isn't explained anywhere on the official documentation. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why but getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN); makes it fail in my code.  I have to ensure this is NOT in the code to make it work.

Comment: Thanks this works but the bars go full transparent instead of a soft gradient like they were in KitKat. Should I add a custom soft gradient in order to achieve such effect? Thanks

Comment: Yes, bars will be totally transparent. Then it will be very advisable to add a gradient (as a FrameLayout at the bottom of another FrameLayout or RelativeLayout) like the one shown on Android 4.4, above all for the navigation bar.

Comment: @AxeEffect how would you tell the view containing the gradient to start behind the status bar rather than below it?

Answer (score 9):

Add below line to your style:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

To clarify [@suckgamony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26571307/5025060) to this question:

- ***Under Lollipop and above***, setting `android:statusBarColor` or `android:navigationBarColor` to `@android:color/transparent` will make the **Status Bar** or **Navigation Bar** (respectively) completely transparent, unless:
- `android:windowTranslucentStatus` or `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` is set to true, in which case the **Status Bar** or **Navigation Bar** (respectively) is set to the solid transparent color @AxeEffect describes (again, under Lollipop and above);
- `android:statusBarColor` and `android:navigationBarColor` may only be used with Android version 21 (Lollipop 5.0) or higher.  As described in [the referred to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26571307/5025060), `android:windowTranslucentStatus` or `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` when used with Kitkat provide transparent gradients rather than full transparency.