# Change the style of status bar elements in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, material-design

How to change style of status bar elements in android (Material design). I wanted to do something like this...**I want to change color of time and battery not only the background of the status bar** [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474125/android-4-4-translucent-status-and-navigation-bars-style-on-android-5-0

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in you styles.xml.
The colorPrimary is for the action bar and the colorPrimaryDark is for the status bar.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

This picture from developer android explains more about color pallete. You can read more on this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidMainFest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

in values/style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_bg_splash</item>
</style>
```